# (MySQL - Coldfusion/Lucee) - One MySQL Statement, Multiple Inserts - How to get EACH subsubCategoryID?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I'm passing a list of IDs to my insert function. I'm inserting the parentID and the subcategoryID into my database via one sql statement with multiple inserts. This works just fine. However now the rquirements have been altered and now I need to get back some information from each insert.

Using the code below, I added `SELECT last_insert_id() as subsubCategoryID` and the query returned only the first inserted record (I actually expected to only get the very last one inserted not the first one so that was a surprise). Is it possible to get back EACH of the subsubcategoryIDs for each insert or would that require looping over the insert statement and breaking the multiple inserts into distinct insert statements?

```
for (item in listToArray(local.formData, ",")) { 
    local.values &= "(44, " & item & "," & local.formData.userID &")," ;
}

local.values = left(local.values,len(local.values)-1) ;

local.sql = "
    INSERT INTO table (parentID, subcategoryID, userID) 
    VALUES " & local.values & "
    ; SELECT last_insert_id() as subsubCategoryID;
"
writeDump(local.sql);
```

Comment: You need to do the inserts individually to get back the generated ID of each insert.

Comment: "would that require looping over the insert statement" AFAIK, yes. Some databases support capturing multiple id's, like with SQL Server and the `output` clause, but I don't think MySQL's supports that. Though you should be able to drop the last_insert_id() and just use cfquery's `result` attribute.  IIRC it doesn't support multiple id's, but ... wouldn't swear to it.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation guys. I took a break and came back with a new idea (see answer) that as tested works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to leave the original query as-is (without the `SELECT last_insert_id() as subsubCategoryID`) and then at the end perform a lookup (select statement) that will return the subsubcategoryIDs. This will only be two database connection opposed to the multiple database connections that would be required if I broke up the insert statements just so I could append `SELECT last_insert_id() as subsubCategoryID` after each insert statement.

** UPDATE ** Based on a comment made below by Ageax, I'm adding this update for clarity in case someone else runs across this SO Question... When I say "at the end perform a look up" I mean the end of the process and not the end of the query **

Comment: Yeah, it's a tradeoff. Many connections, temp tables or a single lookup. One issue with the latter is it isn't thread safe, so isn't guaranteed to get the id's just inserted. How much of an issue that is depends on the app.

Comment: You make a good point on the thread safe reference. Luckily for my scenario, I know enough details that I can narrow the result set down to just the inserted records.

Comment: Well, multiple threads inserting the same information at the same time, could make it impossible to distinguish between records inserted by the current thread versus others. That can be ok in some apps, but can be very, very bad in others. So thought it was worth mentioning :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out stored procedures.
I envision a block of text with delimiters like the pipe symbol, which are broken apart and inserted in a begin transaction/commit.